# How do I force conversion char[] to char* in template instantiation?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, option-type, c-strings

Let's say I have a function:

```
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
std::optional<T> foo(T const &input);
```

It accepts a value, attempts to work with a copy of it and returns said copy on success (`std::nullopt` on fail).

But the problem is, when a string literal is passed into such function, an error `T in optional<T> must meet the Cpp17Destructible requirements` occurs.

It's caused by `static_assert(is_object_v<_Ty> && is_destructible_v<_Ty> && !is_array_v<_Ty>, ...)` defined in `<optional>`.

The next expression works correctly:

```
foo((char const*) "bar");
```

This one fails:

```
foo("bar");
```

The question is, how do I force the compiler to implicitly convert `char const[]` to `char const*`?

P. S. I know that it could be done by simply overloading the function, by I'm not too keen on code duplication it causes, so I'm curious whether an alternative solution is applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really what you asked for, though consider that not much repetition is needed:

```
template <int s>
std::optional<const char*> foo(const char (&str)[s]) {
    return foo(&str[0]);
}
```

or simpler:

```
std::optional<char const*> foo(char const *input) { 
    return foo<char const *>(input); 
}
```

Comment: I don't think I agree with `std::string` used here, as it's a potentially expensive implicit heap-memory allocation.

Comment: @JohnCvelth oh sorry thats an articaft of me first misunderstanding that you want to convert to `std::string`. fixed

Comment: it seems that, curiously enough, just `std::optional<char const*> foo(char const *input) { return foo<char const *>(input); }` is enough. It seems, where there are no templates involved, implicit conversions work as intended.

Comment: @JohnCvelth oh right, the non-template overload wins. Thats of course much easier, didnt consider it ;)

Comment: @JohnCvelth I added it. First I didn't understand why it works, but then I realized that SFINAE will discard the invalid "pass by reference" overload because `std::optional<T>` is invalid when `T` is reference to array

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Rewrote the answer. With return type deduction, this would be convenient.

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T const &input){
    auto copy {std::move(input)};
    // ...
    return std::optional{std::move(copy)};
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it std::optional<char>?

Comment: but I'm still loosing `const`-qualifier on all other "overloads" this way.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that `std::decay_t` removes const.

Comment: @JohnCvelth I rewrote the answer.

Comment: the new answer would probably cause an unrelated problem: a lot of `return something` statements could be found inside the function. As it uses `if constexpr` in combination with `<type_traits>` to decide what to do with received value. As a result, I'd prefer return type to be explicit, if possible.